# Trouble Aligning Row On Webpage

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a webpage and I am getting stuck with getting another line to go below my content. I'm using flexbox and Bootstrap. When I try to add another it goes next to the "Your Name" section.

I have everything wrapped up in containers, so I would think it would move down to the next line.
[image]

```css
#search {
    width: 500px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js"
        integrity="sha384-rOA1PnstxnOBLzCLMcre8ybwbTmemjzdNlILg8O7z1lUkLXozs4DHonlDtnE7fpc"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".//style.css">
    <title>Flexbox Practice</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container d-flex">
        <div class="sidebar d-flex flex-column justify-content-start align-items-left w-25">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor"
                    class="bi bi-puzzle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path
                        d="M3.112 3.645A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 4.605 2H7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.382c0 .696-.497 1.182-.872 1.469a.459.459 0 0 0-.115.118.113.113 0 0 0-.012.025L6.5 4.5v.003l.003.01c.004.01.014.028.036.053a.86.86 0 0 0 .27.194C7.09 4.9 7.51 5 8 5c.492 0 .912-.1 1.19-.24a.86.86 0 0 0 .271-.194.213.213 0 0 0 .036-.054l.003-.01v-.008a.112.112 0 0 0-.012-.025.459.459 0 0 0-.115-.118c-.375-.287-.872-.773-.872-1.469V2.5A.5.5 0 0 1 9 2h2.395a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.493 1.645L12.645 6.5h.237c.195 0 .42-.147.675-.48.21-.274.528-.52.943-.52.568 0 .947.447 1.154.862C15.877 6.807 16 7.387 16 8s-.123 1.193-.346 1.638c-.207.415-.586.862-1.154.862-.415 0-.733-.246-.943-.52-.255-.333-.48-.48-.675-.48h-.237l.243 2.855A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.395 14H9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-.382c0-.696.497-1.182.872-1.469a.459.459 0 0 0 .115-.118.113.113 0 0 0 .012-.025L9.5 11.5v-.003l-.003-.01a.214.214 0 0 0-.036-.053.859.859 0 0 0-.27-.194C8.91 11.1 8.49 11 8 11c-.491 0-.912.1-1.19.24a.859.859 0 0 0-.271.194.214.214 0 0 0-.036.054l-.003.01v.002l.001.006a.113.113 0 0 0 .012.025c.016.027.05.068.115.118.375.287.872.773.872 1.469v.382a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H4.605a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.493-1.645L3.356 9.5h-.238c-.195 0-.42.147-.675.48-.21.274-.528.52-.943.52-.568 0-.947-.447-1.154-.862C.123 9.193 0 8.613 0 8s.123-1.193.346-1.638C.553 5.947.932 5.5 1.5 5.5c.415 0 .733.246.943.52.255.333.48.48.675.48h.238l-.244-2.855z" />
                </svg>
                <h1>Dashboard</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul class="px-2 mb-4">
                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-house-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="m8 3.293 6 6V13.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2 13.5V9.293l6-6zm5-.793V6l-2-2V2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5z" />
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M7.293 1.5a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0l6.647 6.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 2.207 1.354 8.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L7.293 1.5z" />
                        </svg>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-card-checklist" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M14.5 3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-13a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13zm-13-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3.5v9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 14h13a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 14.5 2h-13z" />
                            <path
                                d="M7 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm-1.496-.854a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-.5-.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708l.146.147 1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0zM7 9.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm-1.496-.854a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708l.146.147 1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z" />
                        </svg>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-chat-right-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M14 0a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12.793a.5.5 0 0 1-.854.353l-2.853-2.853a1 1 0 0 0-.707-.293H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12z" />
                        </svg>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Messages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-clock-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8 3.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V9a.5.5 0 0 0 .252.434l3.5 2a.5.5 0 0 0 .496-.868L8 8.71V3.5z" />
                        </svg>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">History</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-card-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M14.5 3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-13a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13zm-13-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3.5v9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 14h13a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 14.5 2h-13z" />
                            <path
                                d="M5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7A.5.5 0 0 1 5 8zm0-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm-1-5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zM4 8a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm0 2.5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0z" />
                        </svg>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tasks</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-people-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M7 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 5-4 5 3 5 4-1 1-1 1H7zm4-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z" />
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M5.216 14A2.238 2.238 0 0 1 5 13c0-1.355.68-2.75 1.936-3.72A6.325 6.325 0 0 0 5 9c-4 0-5 3-5 4s1 1 1 1h4.216z" />
                            <path d="M4.5 8a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5z" />
                        </svg>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Communities</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <ul class="px-2">
                        <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-gear-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M9.405 1.05c-.413-1.4-2.397-1.4-2.81 0l-.1.34a1.464 1.464 0 0 1-2.105.872l-.31-.17c-1.283-.698-2.686.705-1.987 1.987l.169.311c.446.82.023 1.841-.872 2.105l-.34.1c-1.4.413-1.4 2.397 0 2.81l.34.1a1.464 1.464 0 0 1 .872 2.105l-.17.31c-.698 1.283.705 2.686 1.987 1.987l.311-.169a1.464 1.464 0 0 1 2.105.872l.1.34c.413 1.4 2.397 1.4 2.81 0l.1-.34a1.464 1.464 0 0 1 2.105-.872l.31.17c1.283.698 2.686-.705 1.987-1.987l-.169-.311a1.464 1.464 0 0 1 .872-2.105l.34-.1c1.4-.413 1.4-2.397 0-2.81l-.34-.1a1.464 1.464 0 0 1-.872-2.105l.17-.31c.698-1.283-.705-2.686-1.987-1.987l-.311.169a1.464 1.464 0 0 1-2.105-.872l-.1-.34zM8 10.93a2.929 2.929 0 1 1 0-5.86 2.929 2.929 0 0 1 0 5.858z" />
                            </svg>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-book-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M8 1.783C7.015.936 5.587.81 4.287.94c-1.514.153-3.042.672-3.994 1.105A.5.5 0 0 0 0 2.5v11a.5.5 0 0 0 .707.455c.882-.4 2.303-.881 3.68-1.02 1.409-.142 2.59.087 3.223.877a.5.5 0 0 0 .78 0c.633-.79 1.814-1.019 3.222-.877 1.378.139 2.8.62 3.681 1.02A.5.5 0 0 0 16 13.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 0-.293-.455c-.952-.433-2.48-.952-3.994-1.105C10.413.809 8.985.936 8 1.783z" />
                            </svg>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tasks</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-shield-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M5.072.56C6.157.265 7.31 0 8 0s1.843.265 2.928.56c1.11.3 2.229.655 2.887.87a1.54 1.54 0 0 1 1.044 1.262c.596 4.477-.787 7.795-2.465 9.99a11.775 11.775 0 0 1-2.517 2.453 7.159 7.159 0 0 1-1.048.625c-.28.132-.581.24-.829.24s-.548-.108-.829-.24a7.158 7.158 0 0 1-1.048-.625 11.777 11.777 0 0 1-2.517-2.453C1.928 10.487.545 7.169 1.141 2.692A1.54 1.54 0 0 1 2.185 1.43 62.456 62.456 0 0 1 5.072.56z" />
                            </svg>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group row pt-2">
                    <label class="col-form-label" for="search"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16"
                            height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
                        </svg></label>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input class="form-control rounded" type="text" name="search" id="search">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-2 ml-3">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                    class="bi bi-bell-fill mt-2" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path
                        d="M8 16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2H6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2zm.995-14.901a1 1 0 1 0-1.99 0A5.002 5.002 0 0 0 3 6c0 1.098-.5 6-2 7h14c-1.5-1-2-5.902-2-7 0-2.42-1.72-4.44-4.005-4.901z" />

                </svg>
                <h4 class="px-1">Your Name</h4>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>









    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing I noticed when I looked at your webpage is that the layout just doesn't fit the look. You have 3 columns with the left most column being the only column you seem to have divided correctly.

Thinking about it using shapes, the top row should be its own rectangle. The space below can be two rectangles. One holding the sidebar and one holding the body or whitespace in this case.

First thing I did was change some naming conventions. You'll want to use articles and sections sometimes to help differentiate between separate parts in your code. I took the top parts and put them into a **header** tag. From there I set it to **flex row** and **justify-content-between**.

```
        <header class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor"
                    class="bi bi-puzzle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path
                        d="M3.112 3.645A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 4.605 2H7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.382c0 .696-.497 1.182-.872 1.469a.459.459 0 0 0-.115.118.113.113 0 0 0-.012.025L6.5 4.5v.003l.003.01c.004.01.014.028.036.053a.86.86 0 0 0 .27.194C7.09 4.9 7.51 5 8 5c.492 0 .912-.1 1.19-.24a.86.86 0 0 0 .271-.194.213.213 0 0 0 .036-.054l.003-.01v-.008a.112.112 0 0 0-.012-.025.459.459 0 0 0-.115-.118c-.375-.287-.872-.773-.872-1.469V2.5A.5.5 0 0 1 9 2h2.395a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.493 1.645L12.645 6.5h.237c.195 0 .42-.147.675-.48.21-.274.528-.52.943-.52.568 0 .947.447 1.154.862C15.877 6.807 16 7.387 16 8s-.123 1.193-.346 1.638c-.207.415-.586.862-1.154.862-.415 0-.733-.246-.943-.52-.255-.333-.48-.48-.675-.48h-.237l.243 2.855A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.395 14H9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-.382c0-.696.497-1.182.872-1.469a.459.459 0 0 0 .115-.118.113.113 0 0 0 .012-.025L9.5 11.5v-.003l-.003-.01a.214.214 0 0 0-.036-.053.859.859 0 0 0-.27-.194C8.91 11.1 8.49 11 8 11c-.491 0-.912.1-1.19.24a.859.859 0 0 0-.271.194.214.214 0 0 0-.036.054l-.003.01v.002l.001.006a.113.113 0 0 0 .012.025c.016.027.05.068.115.118.375.287.872.773.872 1.469v.382a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H4.605a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.493-1.645L3.356 9.5h-.238c-.195 0-.42.147-.675.48-.21.274-.528.52-.943.52-.568 0-.947-.447-1.154-.862C.123 9.193 0 8.613 0 8s.123-1.193.346-1.638C.553 5.947.932 5.5 1.5 5.5c.415 0 .733.246.943.52.255.333.48.48.675.48h.238l-.244-2.855z" />
                </svg>
                <h1>Dashboard</h1>
            </div>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group row pt-2">
                    <label class="col-form-label" for="search"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16"
                            height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
                        </svg></label>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input class="form-control rounded" type="text" name="search" id="search">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-2 ml-3">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                    class="bi bi-bell-fill mt-2" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path
                        d="M8 16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2H6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2zm.995-14.901a1 1 0 1 0-1.99 0A5.002 5.002 0 0 0 3 6c0 1.098-.5 6-2 7h14c-1.5-1-2-5.902-2-7 0-2.42-1.72-4.44-4.005-4.901z" />

                </svg>
                <h4 class="px-1">Your Name</h4>
            </div>
        </header>
```

As for the body portion. I set that into two **article** tags inside of one **section** tag. One for the sidebar and one for the body.

```
        <section class="d-flex flex-row w-100">
            <article class="sidebar d-flex flex-column justify-content-start align-items-left w-25">
                    <ul class="px-2 mb-4">
                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-house-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                    d="m8 3.293 6 6V13.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2 13.5V9.293l6-6zm5-.793V6l-2-2V2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5z" />
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                    d="M7.293 1.5a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0l6.647 6.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 2.207 1.354 8.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L7.293 1.5z" />
                            </svg>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-card-checklist" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M14.5 3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-13a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13zm-13-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3.5v9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 14h13a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 14.5 2h-13z" />
                                <path
                                    d="M7 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm-1.496-.854a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-.5-.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708l.146.147 1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0zM7 9.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm-1.496-.854a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708l.146.147 1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z" />
                            </svg>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-chat-right-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M14 0a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12.793a.5.5 0 0 1-.854.353l-2.853-2.853a1 1 0 0 0-.707-.293H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12z" />
                            </svg>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Messages</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-clock-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8 3.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V9a.5.5 0 0 0 .252.434l3.5 2a.5.5 0 0 0 .496-.868L8 8.71V3.5z" />
                            </svg>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">History</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-card-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M14.5 3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-13a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13zm-13-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3.5v9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 14h13a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 14.5 2h-13z" />
                                <path
                                    d="M5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7A.5.5 0 0 1 5 8zm0-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm-1-5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zM4 8a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm0 2.5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0z" />
                            </svg>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tasks</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-people-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M7 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 5-4 5 3 5 4-1 1-1 1H7zm4-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z" />
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                    d="M5.216 14A2.238 2.238 0 0 1 5 13c0-1.355.68-2.75 1.936-3.72A6.325 6.325 0 0 0 5 9c-4 0-5 3-5 4s1 1 1 1h4.216z" />
                                <path d="M4.5 8a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5z" />
                            </svg>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Communities</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div>
                        <ul class="px-2">
                            <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                    class="bi bi-gear-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path
                                        d="M9.405 1.05c-.413-1.4-2.397-1.4-2.81 0l-.1.34a1.464 1.464 0 0 1-2.105.872l-.31-.17c-1.283-.698-2.686.705-1.987 1.987l.169.311c.446.82.023 1.841-.872 2.105l-.34.1c-1.4.413-1.4 2.397 0 2.81l.34.1a1.464 1.464 0 0 1 .872 2.105l-.17.31c-.698 1.283.705 2.686 1.987 1.987l.311-.169a1.464 1.464 0 0 1 2.105.872l.1.34c.413 1.4 2.397 1.4 2.81 0l.1-.34a1.464 1.464 0 0 1 2.105-.872l.31.17c1.283.698 2.686-.705 1.987-1.987l-.169-.311a1.464 1.464 0 0 1 .872-2.105l.34-.1c1.4-.413 1.4-2.397 0-2.81l-.34-.1a1.464 1.464 0 0 1-.872-2.105l.17-.31c.698-1.283-.705-2.686-1.987-1.987l-.311.169a1.464 1.464 0 0 1-2.105-.872l-.1-.34zM8 10.93a2.929 2.929 0 1 1 0-5.86 2.929 2.929 0 0 1 0 5.858z" />
                                </svg>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Settings</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                    class="bi bi-book-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path
                                        d="M8 1.783C7.015.936 5.587.81 4.287.94c-1.514.153-3.042.672-3.994 1.105A.5.5 0 0 0 0 2.5v11a.5.5 0 0 0 .707.455c.882-.4 2.303-.881 3.68-1.02 1.409-.142 2.59.087 3.223.877a.5.5 0 0 0 .78 0c.633-.79 1.814-1.019 3.222-.877 1.378.139 2.8.62 3.681 1.02A.5.5 0 0 0 16 13.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 0-.293-.455c-.952-.433-2.48-.952-3.994-1.105C10.413.809 8.985.936 8 1.783z" />
                                </svg>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tasks</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                    class="bi bi-shield-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path
                                        d="M5.072.56C6.157.265 7.31 0 8 0s1.843.265 2.928.56c1.11.3 2.229.655 2.887.87a1.54 1.54 0 0 1 1.044 1.262c.596 4.477-.787 7.795-2.465 9.99a11.775 11.775 0 0 1-2.517 2.453 7.159 7.159 0 0 1-1.048.625c-.28.132-.581.24-.829.24s-.548-.108-.829-.24a7.158 7.158 0 0 1-1.048-.625 11.777 11.777 0 0 1-2.517-2.453C1.928 10.487.545 7.169 1.141 2.692A1.54 1.54 0 0 1 2.185 1.43 62.456 62.456 0 0 1 5.072.56z" />
                                </svg>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Privacy</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </article>
            <article class="container d-flex flex-column w-75 bg-primary">
                <h1>Body</h1>
            </article>
        </section>
```

Hopefully this helps. Planning is something you definitely want to consider when dealing with these sorts of pages. Think about headers, sidebars, body and how you can give them all their own shapes/space on the page.